# Request method 'GET' not supported のエラーを解決したい

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

以下のエラーを解決したい。

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
```

ログイン画面でログインし検索画面でテキストボックスをクリックすると、ブラウザが固まって上のエラーが出ます。

環境はMac, Eclipse 2020, MySQL

よろしくお願いします。

````
@Controller
public class UserController {

  @Autowired
  UserService sevi;

  @Autowired
  UserRepository rep;
  //初期画面
  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  String login(@ModelAttribute UserForm form) {
    //List<User> list = sevi.findAll();
    //UserForm form1 = new UserForm();
    //model.addAttribute("form", new UserForm());
    //model.addAttribute("list", list);
    return "login";
  }
  //ログイン
  @PostMapping("yeah")
  public String Login(
      @RequestParam String id,
      @RequestParam String pass,
      @Validated @ModelAttribute UserForm form,
      BindingResult result,
      Model model
      ) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
      return login(form);
    }
    User u = sevi.Login(id, pass);
    if (null == sevi.Login(u.getId(), u.getPass())) {
      return "login";
    } else {
      return "search";
    }
  }
  //検索
  @PostMapping("search")
  public ModelAndView search(@RequestParam String name,
      ModelAndView mav) {
    List<User> list = sevi.findBynameLike(name);
    mav.addObject("list", list);
    mav.setViewName("/search");
    return mav;
  }```
````

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserForm{
  @NotBlank
  private String id;
  @NotBlank
  private String pass;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
@Getter
@Setter
public class User{
  @Id
  @Column(name="id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private String id;
  @Column(name = "pass")
  private String pass;
  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;
  @Column(name = "kana")
  private String kana;
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,String>{

  List<User> findBynameLike(String name);
}
```

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    public List<User> findBynameLike(String name){
    return userRepository.findBynameLike(name + "%");
    }

    public List<User> findAll() {
      return userRepository.findAll();
  }

    public void insert(User user) {
      userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public void update(User user) {
      userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public void delete(String id) {
      userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    public Optional<User> selectById(String id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public User Login(String id,String pass) {
      User u = userRepository.getById(id);
      if (null != u) {
        if (u.getPass().equals(pass)) {
          return u;
        }
      } else {
      }
      return null;
    }
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>ログイン画面</h2>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/yeah}" th:object="${userForm}" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>id:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="id" th:field="*{id}" />
<span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('id')}" th:errors="*{id}"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>pass:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="pass" th:field="*{pass}" />
<span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('pass')}" th:errors="*{pass}"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<! DOCTYPE html >
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>検索画面</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
    <h2>社員情報検索</h2>
    <h3>※前方一致で検索します</h3>
    <form action="/search" method="post">
        <p>
            ID<input type="text" name="name"><br>
            <!--  名前<input type="text" name="name"><br>
            カナ<input type="text" name="name"><br>-->
            <button type="submit">検索</button>
            <button type="submit">新規登録</button>
    </form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>名前</th>
            <th>カナ</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="list : ${list}" th:object="${list}">
            <td th:text="*{id}"></td>
            <td th:text="*{name}"></td>
            <td th:text="*{kana}"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Comment: "検索画面でテキストボックスをクリックすると" の "*テキストボックス*" とは、社員情報検索画面のID入力欄のことでよいしょうか。もしそうだとすると、記載されているコード中には当問題が発生するような処理は無さそうに見えます。(記載されているエラーが発生するのは、例えば `/search` を直接ブラウザで開いた場合などです。また、本当にテキストボックスクリック時にこのエラーが出ているのだとすると、何か(質問文に記載されていない)JavaScriptでの制御が行われているのではないかと思われますが、そういった処理はないでしょうか。)[DevToolsのNetworkタブ](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/)で、`405` が発生するタイミングや通信内容を見れば当たりがつくかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

探索画面のDOCTYPEが離れているからでは？
その他の処理でおかしなところは見当たりませんね。